# Spring JPA Data ManyToOne column sorting with child enitity attribute and also allowing null value

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Having two tables, example Employee and Address entity. I need to sort by Address entity country name. I have used like "address.country" which sort by
country name. But dropping null address rows in Employee table. Need to retain rows with address_pk is null as well as sorted rows based country name

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee")
public class Employee {
    private Address address;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_pk", nullable = true)
    public Address getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(Address address) {
        this.address = address;
    }
}
```

Comment: a simple `sort by` doesn't drop any rows. your mistake is somewhere else

Comment: I assume you try to use the inbuilt sort feature?

Comment: *I have used like "address.country"*. Where exactly in the posted code do you do any kind of sorting?

Comment: Where is your SQL? You know, what your chosen JPA provider executes, and is shown in its log? This is often referred to as debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use JPA default methods like this:

```
employeeRepository.findAll(sort);
```

then the auto-generated query will use inner-join. So all of the lines where an employee has no address-reference will be excluded from the result.

You have to create a custom query, like:

```
@Query(value="select e from Employee e LEFT JOIN e.address a ORDER BY a.country");
Page<Employee> findAllSorted();
```